# Inherit a model and create new xml file for it in odoo

Tags: inheritance, odoo, development-environment

i am new in odoo development.**i have to create new xml file for    inherited model,and also need to add some extra fields**.

how can i do it?anyone help me please

i tried below program, but i didn't get  inherited model ,only creating new model.when adding model name stock.picking in xml model name i got inherited model but my new field are not there.really ,i don't know how exactly do this.

.py file is

```
class LoadingChart(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.picking'
    _name = 'loading.chart'
     _description = "Loading Chart"

    nf_date = fields.Date(string="Loading Date")
    nf_date1 = fields.Datetime(string="Date")
    nf_reference = fields.Char(string="Reference")
    nf_seq = fields.Char(string='Loading Sequence', required=True, copy=False, readonly=True,
                         index=True, default=lambda self: _('New'))
```

.xml file is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<odoo>
   
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="nf_unloading_view">
        <field name="name">Loading.chart.tree</field>
        <field name="model">loading.chart</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree>
                <field name="nf_date"/>
                <field name="nf_date1"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>

     <record id="stock_picking_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">stock.picking.form</field>
        <field name="model">loading.chart</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form>

                <sheet>
                    <div class='oe_title'>
                        <h1>
                            <field name="nf_seq" readonly="1"/>

                        </h1>
                    </div>
                    <group>
                        <group>
                             <field name="nf_date"/>
                             <field name="nf_date1"/>
                        </group>
                          <group>
                             <field name=" nf_reference"/>
                             
                        </group>
                    </group>

    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="loading_chart_action_window">
        <field name="name">loading Chart</field>
        <field name="res_model">loading.chart</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>
    <!--*************************MENU*****************************************************-->

    <menuitem id="loading_chart_root_menu" name="Loading Chart"
              parent="stock.menu_stock_warehouse_mgmt" action="loading_chart_action_window" sequence="20"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_inherit` and `_name` attributes are the same, Odoo will create a new `model`, check [Classical inheritance](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/addons/orm.html#classical-inheritance) documentation for more details:

> When using the `_inherit` and `_name` attributes together, Odoo creates a new model using the existing one (provided via `_inherit`) as a base. The new model gets all the fields, methods and meta-information (defaults & al) from its base.

To [Extend](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/addons/orm.html#extension) `stock.picking` in-place (add features), do not provide the `_name` then [inherit](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/addons/views.html#inheritance) the stock picking views to add the new fields.

***Example***

Inherit `stock.picking` in-place:

```py
class StockPicking(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.picking'

    nf_date = fields.Date(string="Loading Date")
```

Extend `stock.picking` tree view:

```
<record id="stock_picking_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">stock.picking.tree</field>
    <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.vpicktree"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="scheduled_date" position="after">
            <field name="nf_date"/>
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

Extend `stock.picking` form view:

```
<record id="stock_picking_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">stock.picking.form</field>
    <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_picking_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="date_deadline" position="after">
            <field name="nf_date"/>
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```